# How to print a 'null' for any of many values that may have no value

Tags: python, null

I'm running some statistics stuff (example):

```
Chi_min=str(min(chi))
Chi_max=str(max(chi))
Teff_min=str(min(Temp))
Teff_max=str(max(Temp))
Tin_min=str(min(Tin))
Tin_max=str(max(Tin))
Tau_min=str(min(Tau))
Tau_max=str(max(Tau))
Mdots_min=str(min(Mdots))
Mdots_max=str(max(Mdots))
Chi_sdev=str(sp.stats.tstd(chi))
Teff_sdev=str(sp.stats.tstd(Temp))
Tin_sdev=str(sp.stats.tstd(Tin))
Tau_sdev=str(sp.stats.tstd(Tau))
Mdots_sdev=str(sp.stats.tstd(Mdots))
```

and I have the results being printed out onto a single line like so

```
NewResults=NewResults+str(data[RowStar][0])+'\t'+str(RowStar+1)+'\t'+str(ChiThresh)+'\t'+str(BestX)+'\t'+str(Teff)+'\t'+Teff_min+'\t'+Teff_max+'\t'+Teff_sdev+'\t'+Teff_sdev2+'\t'+Teff_med+'\t'+str(Tempin)+'\t'+Tin_min+'\t'+Tin_max+'\t'+Tin_sdev+'\t'+Tin_med
```

I'm missing a few columns when it writes to the file. I suspect that it's not putting anything down for any null values. What is the easiest way to have python print out a value of 'null' for any value that doesn't have any output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to rely on the fact that an empty string evaluates as being `False`.

As such, you can do the following for each entry:

```
Chi_min = str(min(chi)) or "null"
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you could do that. Thank you.

Comment: And rather than repeating all that for every line, you could write a function for it.  :-)